# Error In fill in read.table in R

Tags: r, read.table

I am trying to import the data from the CSV file. The code I used is below

```
New <- read.table("New.csv", fill="TRUE")
```

and below is the CSV file data:

```
Name    Sex Age Score   Aspirations
Rhea    F   18  98  Doctor
John    M   17  90  Engineer
Rads    F   21  87  Air Hostess
```

The R console is sending me an error and I am not sure how to deal with this. I am a beginner in R.

> Error in fill && length(col.names) > cols : invalid 'x' type in 'x &&
>   y'

Comment: Have you tried with `read.csv()`?

Comment: I have tried, but the error is same.

Comment: Since it's a csv file, have you tried removing `fill = TRUE`?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotation marks from TRUE, so it reads

```
New <- read.table("New.csv", fill=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the file path, and ensuring the file type is a CSV. Note an Excel file is not the same thing as a CSV file. You must open the Excel workbook, click File > Save As > CSV, to create the CSV file.

Also, unless you've specified a working directory or saved the CSV to your desktop, you must do so by the following:

`New <- read.csv("C:/Users/YOUR-USERNAME/Desktop/New.csv")`

Note, you must use forward slashes instead of backslashes. You can find the file path by right-clicking and selecting properties.

Let me know if this works.